# Writing classes in different file in c++

Tags: c++, file, class

I am writing a c++ program which consists of 8 classes.

```
1.Vehicle
      derived class 1. Seat
                    2.Door 
2.Passenger
3.Settings
      derived class 1. SeatSettings
                    2. InfotainmentSettings
4.PassengerLocation
```

I don't have any previous experience in c++. While writing the program should I  write all the classes in a single .cpp file or in different .cpp file. If as different .cpp file then parent and derived class should be in same file ?.

Comment: Here you can read about classes http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/classes/ .

Comment: Just as an aside: either `Vehicle` is misnamed, or `Seat` and `Door` should not be derived from it. What functionality do `Seat` and `Vehicle` share - can they both `StartEngine`? _Is_ a `Door` _a_ `Vehicle`? Normally, I would expected derived classes like `Truck` and `StationWagon`.

Answer (score 1):

Really you can write classes in any place of your programs. Inside *h* files, *cpp* files, inside other *classes*, inside *methods* and so on. C++ give complete control under source code of the application.

In general way you describe interface of a class in a *h* files, and implement methods in a *cpp* file. But you can implement inline or template methods in the *h* file.

I think that you should start from [Classes guide](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/classes/), and when you will have knowledges about capability you can select right way to implement  your classes.

Answer (score 0):

You should make a separate .h and .cpp file pair for each class you implement in c++ unless it is a template class or struct

Answer (score 0):

Separate the classes but keep the parent and derived classes in the same file.
Put your class declarations in .h files and the implementations in .cpp files and then include the .h file in its corresponding .cpp file.